# How to obtain the existing Google Analytic clientId on OS X and/or Windows for use with Google Measurement Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-analytics, mfc, measurement-protocol

We are extending our analytic coverage to include actions on our Desktop apps for Windows and Mac OSX.

The Google Measurement Protocol is simple enough to use:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Is there a way that we can extract the existing Google client-id, that is, the id generated by Google and generally stored in a cookie on the computer that uniquely and anonymously identifies the client?

For clarity - you would typically use Javascript to extract it in a web-page as follows;
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie

How do you do the same using a language such as Swift or Objective-C on OS X, or MFC/C++ on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The client id is generated by the Javascript tracking code (or the SDK respectively). So if you use the measurement protocol there is no pre-existing client id that you could extract.

The good news is that you can generate your own. Google Analytics isn't critical w/r/t what it accepts as client id, any string will do - however to serve it's intended purpose it must be unique, so a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is recommended.

Comment: Thanks @elke. The reason we want to use the existing client id is so that we can link future activity with google $ spend. If we run a google campaign and spend money to acquire a new customer, then we can track that goal via our web apps. However, if that visitor downloads one of our apps and purchases via that mechanism instead, then we have no way of being able to link that conversion to a specific campaign, so it is not possible to calculate accurate ROI's. We cld generate the UUID as suggested, but then we start a fresh sequence, instead of following an existing sequence.

Comment: I understand that, I just do not see how you have an existing client id to extract on the computer that installs the app (and you can't extract it from GA because that would require that you identify the user in the first place).  If your site and app have a login you maybe could use the userId feature (passing in e.g. SHA256 hash of name and/or mailadress), which would give you some additional value for your reporting (cross device tracking).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use the [User ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) feature of Google Analytics. This feature lets you send your own ID instead of using the randomly generated Client ID (that is stored in a cookie).

So if the user visits your website and identifies themselves (e.g. logs in), then you would sent their "customer ID" using the User ID feature. Then, if that user goes on to install your desktop application and also identifies themselves (by logging in again), then you would use the measurement protocol to send the same "customer ID". You would do this by using the `&uid` measurement protocol parameter. Google Analytics will then identify this as the same user an you will basically get x-device behaviour in GA. This will allow you to figure out that campaign A drove a website visit as well as an eventual desktop app download.

Comment: Thanks @faridghar. This is more or less the approach we're taking at the moment - or at least working towards. We currently don't require login before downloading. I am still hoping to find an alternative.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to get them to login _before_ downloading. They login could technically happen within the desktop software itself. Also, it doesn't really even have to be a login. It could just be them giving you their email address. You can then MD5 hash this email and use that is the GA User ID. You would have to do the same on the website so that the User IDs match.